# Object is of type 'unknown' typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, fetch, fetch-api, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have a createAsyncThunk function. With status 401, I create a new error through the constructor and throw this error. In catch, why can't I get her message field? -> 'err' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)

```
export const add = createAsyncThunk<any, Product, { state: RootState }>(
    'product/addToCart',
    async (product, { getState, dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${base_url}/main/wishlist/card`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(product),
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${getState().user.jwtToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        try {
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log("Successful addition of a product to the wishlist");
                return data;
            }
            if (response.status === 400) {
                dispatch(refreshTokenRotation({}));
                dispatch(add(product));
            }
            if (response.status === 401) {
                throw new Error("Invalid or missing jwtToken");
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            return rejectWithValue(err.message);//'err' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)
        }
    }
)
```

I tried adding the argument type but it didn't help

```
catch (error: Error) {
    console.log(error);
    return rejectWithValue(error.message);
}
```

Comment: `return rejectWithValue(error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error')`

Comment: maybe unrelated: since you are using redux-toolkit, maybe you could try its RTK Query which won't need to handle these logics

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can `throw` everything, not just `Error` objects. Some examples:

```js
throw 1;
throw "something";
throw [1, "something"];
throw { some: "thing" }
```

So, in TypeScript, a `catch` will always be typed `unknown`, as you have no idea what was actually `throw`n by another function call. There is no guarantee that it's an `Error` instance.

You will have to check first what you actually have - for example using the `instanceOf` operator, or a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).